# In dotnet-publish, do property overrides propagate to all other referenced projects? Can that be controlled?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am attempting to build a project with overridden properties.

```
dotnet publish MyProject.csproj -f netcoreapp3.0 -c Release -r win-x86 /p:CopyOutputSymbolsToPublishDirectory=false /p:OutputType=WinExe
```

However, it results in a build error in a classlib dependency.

```
error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

I can only assume that the `/p:OutputType=WinExe` is propagating down and overriding their properties too. Is there way to stop that? Can I have that override only apply to the target project?

Oddly enough, if I build without `/p:OutputType=WinExe` and then immediately build *with* `/p:OutputType=WinExe`, it succeeds. (The dependencies are built and cached, I guess.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this as an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3920) onto GitHub and received [this reply](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3920#issuecomment-555143224).

> Specifying a property at the command line causes it to be set as a [global property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties); global properties are by default inherited by projects built as `ProjectReference`s (or otherwise using the `MSBuild` task inside MSBuild).
>
> There's no trivial way to disable this but there are some options:
>
> 1. Use a different property (maybe `MyProjectOutputType`) that isn't used by other projects and set `OutputType` based on that in `MyProject.csproj`.
> 2. Tell `MyProject.csproj` to avoid passing `OutputType` metadata to its references by setting the metadata `UndefineProperties="OutputType"` on all `ProjectReferences` it has (probably via an [item definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-definitions?view=vs-2019) rather than on every `ProjectReference` XML node)